# I am unable to drag file from my WPF application to Outlook 2013 Email

Tags: wpf, outlook, drag-and-drop

I have implemented drag and drop in my WPF application. It is working fine with Explorer. It is copying files in both direction.

But the issue is with Outlook. I am unable to share files with Outlook 2013 or later version. If we drag file from Explorer to new Email in Outlook then it add to Attachments of the email but while dragging from my Application, I can't add it.

But yes, If some file is already added and we drag a file from my WPF application and drop to `"Attached: "` field area then it copies.

I am using `Windows 10` and `Outlook 2013`. I have researched many websites but in all places they are showing how to drag-n-drop Outlook Emails into WPF or Outlook Email Attachments into WPF - which is not useful for me.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Exact same problem, I hope someone finds an answer

Comment: Sorry, I didn't find any answer, I guess this is a limitation, and we told our client to drag to `"Attached: "` area only.

Comment: It works for us with outlook 2010 and 2016 -_- whats so different about 2013 :P